# Swapping out a process waiting for I/O completion

Tags: unix, process, scheduling

In UNIX, when a process executing in kernel mode requires a disk read, it goes to sleep. When the disk read is complete, the hardware interrupts the CPU and the interrupt handler wakes up the process. So now, when this process went to sleep state initially, can the swapper process swap this process to the swap device?

This question may seem to be very naive. But I am not very clear about when a process does which transitions. Any pages with very clear descriptions are also welcomed.

Thanks in advnace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can. It hardly will, though, as a very basic implementation of the virtual memory manager would consider locality of reference as a way to go -- and the process is **probably** a very recent managed data in the system.

The *degradation* of this fact you pointed, i.e., a case in which the process may be taken off the primary memory and swapped, is named [**thrashing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29).